# making functions that need to be called in order and pass args modular

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, module, functional-programming

Hey I'm trying to understand functional programming, stay current etc.

I have this gigantic nested node function tha tI'm attempting to refactor into modules. Each function passes an argument to the next, some are async api calls. I've gotten as far as breaking it down into multiple functions but they're still not really modular as each one calls the next function.

I'm wondered if there's a design pattern to totally untangle them so that the names of the other functions don't appear in the functions but can be passed as callbacks or something. Or maybe that's not even appropriate in this case?

I wrote some simpler fake code that approximates my actual problem so you don't have to sift through endless irrelevant specifics:

```
function1Async();

function function1Async() {

  var theArray = [];
  var theData = "";
  var theInfo = "";

  Async.get( /* api */, function(error, data, response) {
    if (error) {
      function4(); // function call
    }

    theData = data[0].infos;

    for (i in data) {
      theInfo = theData[i].info;
      theArray.push(theInfo);
    }

    function2Async(theArray);  // function call
  });
}  

function function2Async(array) {

  var theArray = [];
  var theObject = {}
  var arrayLength = array.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    search = '"' + array[i] + '"';

    T.get(/* api */, {q: trend, search: 50}, function (error, data, response) {

      if (error) {
        theArray.push("error");
      }
      else {
        theObject = {
          "data": data
      }

        theArray.push(theObject);
      }

      if (theArray.length == arrayLength) {
        function3(theArray); // function call
      }

    });
  } 
}

function function3 (array) {

  var theArray = array;

  if (theArray.includes("error") == true) {
    function5(); // function call
  }
  else {
    function4(theArray); // function call
  }
}

function function4(array) {

  var file = 'files/data.json';

  jsonfile.writeFile(file, array, function(err) {
    function5(); // function call
  });

}

function function5() {

  var file = 'files/data.json';

  jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    return res.json(obj);
  });
}
```

Feel free to chime in with any suggestions even if they're not totally related to the question. Like I said I'm just trying to understand this stuff altogether. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `if (error) function4();` supposed to have an `else`? And `for (i in data) {` misses a declaration for `i`.

Comment: Try using promises.